# Publishing Node.js Package to GitHub Packages - Error ENEEDAUTH

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, github-actions, github-package-registry

**Hello everyone I am trying to publish my NPM package to GitHub packages using this yaml:**

```yaml
    # This workflow will run tests using node and then publish a package to GitHub Packages when a release is created
    # For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages

    name: Node.js Package (GHP)

    on:
      release:
        types: [created]

    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
            with:
              node-version: 18
          - run: npm ci
          - run: npm test

      publish-gpr:
        needs: build
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
          contents: read
          packages: write
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
            with:
              node-version: 18
              registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
          - run: npm ci
          - run: npm publish
            env:
              NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

But I am getting this [error](https://github.com/Roo7K1d/wow-calendar.js/actions/runs/8021749165/job/21914548534) which I don't really understand since this is a template by GitHub themselves.

**[Here](https://github.com/Roo7K1d/wow-calendar.js/blob/main/package.json) You can find my package.json.**

I also tried adding a [.npmrc file](https://github.com/Roo7K1d/wow-calendar.js/blob/main/.npmrc) but my workflow still doesn't work.

I am really hoping you guys can help me with this issue.
(My publish to NPM workflow works just fine btw, I just can't seem to get it to work with GitHub Packages)

**Edit:**
My NPM account is also linked with GitHub.

Comment: The authentication doesn't work. Have you configured the auth token?

Comment: @jabaa i thought the auth token would be generated automatically as per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication

Comment: Could  be an issue with the environment your using, possibly answered here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENEEEDAUTH` error while trying to publish an NPM package to GitHub Packages, it typically indicates an authentication issue (as illustrated by [`npm/cli` issue 6184](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6184)).

> @vighnesh153 I ran into this today, and it turns out that npm doesn't usually accept an auth token via an environment variable like `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` or `NPM_TOKEN`, unless you specify this explicitly in an `.npmrc` file, which the `setup-node` action can create for you

If this does not apply, the rest of your GitHub Actions workflow seems correctly set up for publishing to GitHub Packages, with the `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable being correctly assigned to `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`.

The `.npmrc` (`Roo7K1d:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`) (before you deleted it) tried to associate your package scope with GitHub's npm registry. However, for it to work correctly, you need to make sure that the scope in your `package.json` matches the username or organization name on GitHub exactly and is correctly referenced in `.npmrc`. For GitHub Packages, the correct format usually includes the scope, like:

```
@Roo7K1d:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

And your `package.json` name field should include the scope as well:

```json
{
  "name": "@Roo7K1d/wow-calendar.js",
  ...
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  }
}
```

That is important for [GitHub Packages](https://github.com/features/packages) because it uses the scope to route the package to your account. Your `publishConfig` section seems correctly set, but make sure the scope is included in your package name.

Double-check that your GitHub token has the appropriate permissions for package publication.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `npm publish` fails when the package version is already in the registry. The [`JS-DevTools/npm-publish`](https://github.com/JS-DevTools/npm-publish?tab=readme-ov-file#github-action) action can handle such cases without throwing errors:

```
- name: Push to Github
  uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v3
  with:
    package: 'path/to/package.json'
    registry: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
    token: ${{ github.token }}
    access: 'public'
    provenance: true
```

This way you can control to which registries your package should be published.
I use this in [all my workflows](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-master.yml#L59)

Comment: Nice, that should work too. Upvoted.